# How to fix waitForSyncReply time-out with Meteor/Cordova iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, bluetooth, beacon

We have a Meteor/Cordova app. Development works fine, except when deploying to an actual iPhone device. More often than not the app freezes after a couple of actions, resulting in the following logs in XCode:

```
2016-12-15 13:12:43.546614 museumexplorer[738:169260] #WK: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 35
2016-12-15 13:12:44.554481 museumexplorer[738:169260] #WK: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 36
2016-12-15 13:12:45.559667 museumexplorer[738:169260] #WK: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 37
2016-12-15 13:13:06.239664 museumexplorer[738:169260] #WK: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 38
2016-12-15 13:13:07.248334 museumexplorer[738:169260] #WK: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 39
2016-12-15 13:13:08.260760 museumexplorer[738:169260] #WK: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 40
```

I found it has something to do with the beacons functionality. If I comment out the following code, the freezes don't occur.

```
cordova.plugins.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
    .fail(console.error)
    .done();
```

I'll keep investigating. But if anyone has any bright ideas, I'd love to hear it!

Regards,
Chris

Comment: It seems to be WebKit related when i Google "Connection::waitForSyncReply"

Comment: Very little information to go on here. What actions are you performing?

Comment: Just navigating through the app. Tapping on menu items. It freezes at random moments, sometimes right from the start.

Comment: I am getting the exact error message. Where do you find and comment out the code above? "cordova.plugins.locationManager..."

Comment: Also, I am not using Beacons or locationManager. I am using Meteor/Cordova to build an iOS project. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Neutrino, if you don't use beacons or locationManager you're probably better off creating a new question.

My best guess is that this error indicates a freeze or complete crash of the JavaScript engine. In my case it was probably caused by a huge number of calls to the didRangeBeacons callback combined with the JavaScript overhead of Cordova. Because in a native app this situation would have worked just fine.

Comment: @Neutrino My tip for you is: try removing huge parts of your code until the error is gone. And when it's gone, go back to the code you just removed and start removing parts of that, et cetera. Try to narrow it down that way. That's how I found out it was the beacons code in our case. But it could probably be any heavy JavaScript code.

Comment: How you could found that this problem is related to beacons only? @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently ranging 98 beacons is simply too much, at least with the overhead of the JavaScript callback in a Cordova app. The issue was that startRangingBeaconsInRegion was called for each beacon. We changed it to calling it for each UUID (of which there are only 2). The entire app feels more fluid and responsive now!

So we replace this:

```
var beaconRegion = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.BeaconRegion(beacon._id,
    beacon.uuid,
    beacon.major,
    beacon.minor);

cordova.plugins.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
    .fail(console.error)
    .done();
```

With this:

```
var beaconRegion = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.BeaconRegion('museumexplorerbeacon_' + uuid,
    uuid);

cordova.plugins.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
    .fail(console.error)
    .done();
```

Comment: This may be  a case where running JavaScript in a WebView (as Cordova does) just isn't fast enough.  You might be able to make it work if you make the logic inside your didRangeBeacons callback as fast as possible.    For what it's worth, using native code on iOS, I have successfully ranged a few hundred beacons at the same time on an iPhone 4S, with minimal code in the ranging callback.

Comment: @davidgyoung Even when we have an empty ranging callback, the freezes still occur.

Comment: I'm hitting this same error with this plugin but I'm using the Region Monitoring features instead. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon/issues/287

Answer (score 0):

It might be a hidden bug in WebKit, according to this [WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160240)